# Trying to create a custom ArrayAdapter with ArrayList

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I'm trying to get ArrayList with different variables that i'm getting from a database to display in a customized listview

this is the main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View the balance sheet"
        android:textSize="29sp"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView">

    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the customized layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/description_names"
        android:text="description"
        android:layout_marginTop="25sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"/>

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/values_names"
        android:text="value"
        android:layout_marginTop="25sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="105sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the adapter, i wanted both the ArrayLists from the main activity but it's not working

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<String> mDetails,ArrayList<String> mValues) {
        super(context,R.layout.custom_layout ,mDetails);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,parent,false);
        String details=getItem(position);
        String values=getItem(position);

        TextView description_names=(TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.description_names);
        TextView values_names=(TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.values_names);
        description_names.setText(details);
        return customView;
    }
}
```

main activity

```
ListView listvIew=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
final  ArrayAdapter<String>array=new CustomAdapter(this,mDetails,mValues);

listvIew.setAdapter(array);
private ArrayList<String>mDetails=new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String>mValues=new ArrayList<>();

V3Ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    String value=dataSnapshot.child("records").child("values").getValue(String.class);
    Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: the value is"+value);
    mDetails.add(value);
    mValues.add(value);
    array.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

i'm getting values from the database then putting them in ArrayLists then i'm trying to display them in a customized listview but it's not working when i try to use the second Arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adapter calls from your main activity should be like,

```
CusatomeAdapter adapter;        
adapter = new CusatomeAdapter(mActivity,mList1 ,mList2);        
mListview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

here is your adapter calss

```
public class CusatomeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ArrayList<String> mList1;
    public ArrayList<String> mList2;
    Activity activity;

    public CusatomeAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<String> mList1 , ArrayList<String> mList2){
        super();
        this.activity = activity;
        this.mList1 = mList1;
        this.mList2 = mList2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mList1.size();   //give the size of list here
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_detail, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tv_detail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_detail);

            //same way define another text view and set their value ..

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tv_detail.setText(mList1.get(position).toString());
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_detail;
    }
}
```

Comment: i just tried but it's not showing the listView, the values aren't being display in that listView the whole page is still blank

Comment: are you getting 2 array list with value in to your adapter class ?

Comment: Show me the UI of list view row file what you want to inflate as a row file?

Comment: i'm not getting any listView at all; i'm just getting the values in the android monitor but they can't display at all in the emulator

Comment: Impossible thing! anyway first populate your listview with static data. if you didn't see static data in listview then it clearly seems that ,there is mistake in your xml file

Comment: it's working on one side the arraylist is being used and it's filling the listView but the other isn't        private ArrayList<String>mValues=new ArrayList<>();        so when i use this public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    String value=dataSnapshot.child("records").child("values").getValue(String.class);
    Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: the value is"+value);              mDetails.add(value);
    mValues.add(value);          }      the mDetails is showing something but mValues isn't @ Radhey